# Why does my :checked transition only works on check?

Tags: css, sass

I have a transition that should kick in when a certain checkbox checks or unchecks, but it only happens when it gets checked, but not on uncheck why is that? Can I make it happen on uncheck as well?. This is my style:

```css
&__checkbox {
    display: none;

    &:checked ~ .dt-inst__container {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
&__container {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: $darkPurple;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 7rem auto;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_checked.asp) says, the checked selector selects all the **checked** checkboxes.
You could try the focus selector:

```
&:focus ~ .dt-inst_container {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Or you could add a `(change)` or `on-change` event to the input. When that input changes, you can add/remove a classname from `.dt-inst_container`. That change in classnames then dictates the opacity and visibility.

(this is quickly set out as an example:)
Html:

```
<input (change)="onChange(selectMe)"/>
<div class="change-me" #selectMe></div>
```

Script:

```
public changed;
onChange(target) {
    if (changed) {
        target.classList.remove('exta-class');
    } else {
        target.classList.add('extra-class');
    }
}
```

Easier would be to do this (as an example):

```
<input type="checkbox" #checkInput />
<div (ngClass)=(checkInput.checked ? 'first-class' : 'second-class')></div>
```

Or:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="checkBoxValueBinding" type="checkbox"/>
<div (ngClass)=(checkBoxValueBinding ? 'first-class' : 'second-class')></div>
```